# Significant drop in throughput while running two almost similar XPath queries

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to run a few XPath queries via a C program on an xml file of size 4 mb. I am also calculating the throughput (size of xml file divided by time taken to parse the xml file and the time taken to run the query) There's one thing that quite puzzling to me though. When I run the following XPath expression:

"//what|//is//that"

..I get a throughput of around 700 Megabits/second. But when I run the following expression next:

"what|//is//that"

...I get a throughput of around 36 Megabits/second. Can anyone explain to me why removing the two double slashes at the beginning of the second query leads to such a significant drop in the throughput? I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: That's very odd.  I would have expected the opposite outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `//` to your XPath means to "Start at the root and check all nodes in the document for the following conditions." If you remove it, its expecting to check the current node only.

Example:

```
<root>
    <A>
    </A>
    <D position="I'm here">
        <B>I'm inside D!</B>
        <C>So am I!</C>
    </D>
    <B>I'm not inside D.</B>
    <C>I'm not either.</C>
</root>
```

If I apply the XPath `//C` here, my result will be

```
<C>So am I!</C>

<C>I'm not either.</C>
```

But if I apply the XPath `C`, my result is just `<C>So am I!</C>`

So you are searching the entire document by applying `//`, even if you get the same result.
By just using `what|//is//that`, if the XPath doesn't find a child of the current node with that name, it stops searching. With `//what|//is//that` you're looking for all `is`, `that`, and `what` nodes, which takes longer.

If you're worried about efficiency, then use paths precise as possible (e.g. `root/A/D/C` instead of `//C`)